# pygrep pre-commit hook to check string is present

Tags: grep, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

If I want to write a pre-commit hook to check that, e.g., the string "I love pre-commit" isn't anywhere in my source code, I could do

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: love_statement
      name: Check that I love pre-commit isn't in source code
      types: [python]
      entry: 'I love pre-commit'
      language: pygrep
```

However, what if I want to do this opposite - that is, check that "I love pre-commit" *is* in every source code file? How could I modify my hook so that, instead of failing if "I love pre-commit" is found, it would fail if "I love pre-commit" *isn't* found?

---

this can now be done with

```
args: [--negate]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a few [regex tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/812183) to do this:

```yaml
repos:
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: love_statement
      name: Check that I love pre-commit is in source code
      types: [python]
      args: [--multiline]
      entry: '\A((?!I love pre-commit).)*\Z'
      language: pygrep
```

this combines the following:

- use the rough negative lookbehind pattern from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/812183)
- use `args: [--multiline]` to push `pygrep` into whole-file matching mode
- switch from `^` and `$` (per line anchors) to `\A` and `\Z` (whole string anchors)

here's an example execution:

```
$ git ls-files -- '*.py' | xargs tail -n999
==> t.py <==
print('I do not love pre-commit')

==> t2.py <==
print('I love pre-commit')

$ pre-commit  run --all-files
Check that I love pre-commit is in source code...........................Failed
- hook id: love_statement
- exit code: 1

t.py:1:print('I do not love pre-commit')
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit

Comment: "disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit"

Looks like flattery _is_ a good strategy :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm finding this solution to be slow, even though it works - is there an option to reverse the exit code of `pygrep`? If not, would you take a pull request to add that?

Comment: there is not or I would have suggested it.  A PR may be considered if you can demonstrate a real use case for it

Comment: @AnthonySottile Did inverting the condition every become a thing? I have a use case where we have a version file with a magic string we never want changed. A tox job replaces it. If someone runs it locally we want to make sure they can't commit it if the magic string isn't still there.

Comment: @MikeBarry easy to [check the docs](https://pre-commit.com/#pygrep)